# Accessing IIS Exchange 2010 Throttling Logs (Budget Snapshots)

Tags: iis, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, iis-logs

I'm trying to monitor my EWS app's resource utilization of our Exchange 2010 SP3 server on a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance. I have a decent understanding of the throttling policies, but am not sure where to find the budget snapshots outlined in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/03/10/budget-snapshots-in-the-iis-logs/#comment-29025) article:

> A few components (Outlook Web App, EAS, and EWS) log budget snapshot information to the IIS logs. EWS, notably, includes both a start and an end snapshot. Here is an example of an IIS log entry for EWS (lines are broken up to make it more readable):
>
> 2010-03-09 15:15:12 XX.XXX.XX.X POST /ews/Exchange.asmx
>   ;RC:bfe35012-30fd-499e-90d6-552d0ca89fab;
>   Init>>Conn:0,AD:30000/30000/0%,CAS:54000/54000/0%,AB:30000/30000/0%,RPC:36000/36000/0%,FC:1000/0,Hash:14366112,Sub:20/0;
>   SoapAction=m:GetDelegate;Version=1;RpcC=14;RpcL=687;LdapC=0;LdapL=0;
>   End(17156.25ms)>>Conn:3,AD:30000/30000/0%,CAS:54000/36907/28%,AB:30000/30000/0%,RPC:36000/35985/0%,FC:1000/0,Hash:14366112,Sub:20/0;
>   443 Domain\User XX.XX.XXX.XX - 200 0 0 17468

It seems that these logs contain the information I need to be able to monitor our EWS app's performance and see how close it is to being throttled. I haven't been able to find any other throttling related logs, other than these, but I don't know the path to these. I've checked the IIS logs at `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` and have turned on the throttling related diagnostics logs in the Exchange Management Console and tried to look at them in the Event Viewer, but didn't have any success.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a read of https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/karywa/2016/07/15/exchange-server-20132016-ews-logging-configuration/ . Depending on the update version your running the default location should be \ExchangeInstallPath\V15\Logging\EWS on the CAS server that is processing the EWS requests.